# Circuit Breaker not triggered even after parent circuit breaker limit is exceeded in AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, aws-elasticsearch

**Background**: Our system has a peak point in the morning when we receive high amount of searches, read and write requests which can last upto 10 hours.

**UseCase**: I wanted to force a garbage collection before the peak time. For this I am updating the cluster settings of parent circuit breaker

`indices.breaker.total.limit: "55%"` [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#_limiting_memory_usage)

**Problem**: But even after the JVM grew from 53% to 56% as you can see in the node stats below, JVM was not garbage collected.

**GET /_nodes/stats/jvm**

```
"jvm": {
        "timestamp": 1554375659658,
        "uptime_in_millis": 10960191290,
        "mem": {
          "heap_used_in_bytes": 601959488,
          "heap_used_percent": 56,
          "heap_committed_in_bytes": 1065025536,
          "heap_max_in_bytes": 1065025536,
          "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 243082744,
          "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 251510784,
          "pools": {
            "young": {
              "used_in_bytes": 11959328,
              "max_in_bytes": 69795840,
              "peak_used_in_bytes": 69795840,
              "peak_max_in_bytes": 69795840
            },
            "survivor": {
              "used_in_bytes": 1260248,
              "max_in_bytes": 8716288,
              "peak_used_in_bytes": 8716288,
              "peak_max_in_bytes": 8716288
            },
            "old": {
              "used_in_bytes": 588739912,
              "max_in_bytes": 986513408,
              "peak_used_in_bytes": 739896688,
              "peak_max_in_bytes": 986513408
            }
          }
        }
```

I don't know if this is a problem at the end of AWS ElasticSearch service or core ES. If there is any other way to force a garbage collection I could try that.

Answer (score 0):

Circuit breaker does not force Garbage Collection, rather it will prevent operations from being executed if elasticsearch thinks it will exceed the circuit breaker limit. You might want to check logs to see if requests failed due to CircuitBreakerExceptions.

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html